# Modules of an infinite-dimensional simple algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, projective-module

Let $A$ be an infinite-dimensional algebra (over a closed field of characteristic zero) that is simple (that is, it is simple as an $A-A$-bimodule). Then what can we say about its finitely generated left (right) modules? Will they be projective, or even semisimple.

Comment: *Will they be projective?* I suspect not, because that would imply the right is left semihereditary, and I'm guessing that the field being closed and characteristic zero has anything to do with preventing that. I know for sure it's false if you allow positive characteristic.

Comment: *or even semisimple?* That would cause $A$ itself to be semisimple, right? So no, not in general.